# When is it too late to start growing kang kong?

Tags: spinach

I was just introduced to Kang Kong/Kangkung/Chinese water spinach (Ipomoea aquatica), and was wondering when it's too late to start growing Kang Kong.

Comment: Are you allowed to in your area?  In some places it's considered a noxious weed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too late where you are (from memory, you're in USDA zone 4, pretty much). Start off in early spring from seed, best grown in wide containers, but can be grown in the ground. In tropical and sub tropical areas, it can be harvested year round, will be more of a summer annual where you are

http://balconygardenweb.com/how-to-grow-kangkong-growing-water-spinach/

Comment: http://www.dnr.state.mn.us/invasives/report_aquaticplant.html so for Minnesota, this plant is not yet in the waterways

Comment: It's only invasive if it gets out of control, like planted in a wild location, I would plant it in a metal tub, or a bathtub to produce spinach all year long.